# LLVM Backend: Patterns for register + offset addressing

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

My PIC24 processor offers register + offset addressing. To store a value I added

```
def MOV_reg2offset : InstReg2Offset<0b10011, (outs), (ins GPR:$Wd, GPR:$Ws, Slit10W:$Offset),
                     "mov\t$Ws, [$Wd + $Offset]",
                     [(store GPR:$Ws, (add GPR:$Wd, Slit10W:$Offset) )]>;
```

where GPR is a 16bit register class and Slit10W an even, signed 10 bit literal. Works perfectly!

Now I tried the same for a load instruction:

```
def MOV_offset2reg : InstReg2Offset<0b10010, (outs), (ins GPR:$Wd, GPR:$Ws, Slit10W:$Offset),
                     "mov\t[$Ws + $Offset], $Wd",
                     [(set GPR:$Wd, (load (add GPR:$Ws, Slit10W:$Offset) ))]>;
```

but tablegen crashed with an assertion violation.

### Questions:

- Is there something wrong with the syntax or semantics?
- Or have I exceeded some theoretical limit about what can get matched? Maybe three levels in the pattern is too much?
- Or does it look OK and I should try to update tablegen to the very latest version?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Simple copy and paste error - GPR:$Wd needs to be moved from 'ins' to 'outs'.

Now 'register + offset' addressing works for both read and write without any C++ code. Cool!